# Textbox multiple input types?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to set a textbox to multiple input types? I'd like it to be numeric and password. Is this possible or should I go a different route?

```
@Html.TextBox("CODE", "", new { size = 40, type="password"})
```

EDIT: Forgot to add that the reason I want to set it as numeric is to have it default to the numeric keyboard in android. And yes the password would be numeric characters.

Comment: You'd like it to be `numeric` **and** `password`? Are you saying you want to ensure the password is only numeric characters?

Comment: yes, set it's type as password and then use regular expression validator to verify it's data type.

Comment: As a follow up, do you have model that you're binding this view to that contains a property named `CODE`?

Comment: Forgot to add that the reason I want to set it as numeric is to have it default to the numeric keyboard in android. And yes the password would be numeric characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, html inputs have exactly 1 type. now, the value of input type can be different values and you can validate the value.

so if you want numeric passwords.

1. make the input type password
2. validate the characters entered into
   the input are all digits.

type is semantic, it controls how the input behaves:

- passwords = masked input
- numeric = a number
- email = valid email address
- checkbox = yes/no
- radio = mutually exclusive
- range = inclusive list of numbers
- ....

the value is an instance of the semantic type.

Comment: I found this as well, which is more what I was looking for. But thank you anyway. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/427ec109-610f-4ff2-aa8e-86e19d43c113/